# Kerberos replay attack error within Chrome

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, kerberos

I have problem with Kerberos within Chrome. It seems that Kerberos thinks that the request (HTTP POST) is a replay attack. I'm looking deeper in the source code. And I found that Kerberos's replay cache keeps a record of the request time stamp. And this replay cache always consider the request Authenticator is already in the replay cache so it considers as a replay attacks.

Here is my error message :

```
KrbException: Request is a replay (34)
   at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:300)
   at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:134)
   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:79)
   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:724)
   at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:323)
   at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:267)
   at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:874)
   at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:541)
   at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:323)
   at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:267)
   at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
   at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
   at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)
```

The error is produced only with Chrome (not with IE). I'm using GWT 2.3 and Tomcat 6.

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Probably not ideal but you could upgrade to Tomcat 7 and try the built in SPNEGO authentication.

Comment: Could this will solve the problem ?

Comment: Don't know but it is a different implementation and problems reported via Tomcat's bugzilla get fixed pretty quickly.